# Find formulas for the entries of Mn, where n is a positive integer:

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I need to find a formula for M^n where n is a positive integer.
However, the matrix is not diagonalisable. 
Is there still a solution?

Comment: Doing an exam? Perhaps the question has a mistake? Ask the lecturer maybe?

Comment: Why do you need the matrix to be diagonalizable? Calculate the first 3 terms and write down a formula.
Alternatively, diagonalize the matrix over the complex numbers, find a formula there, and bring it back to the real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $M^2 = 8 M - 16 I$.  Find a formula of the form $M^n = a(n) M + b(n) I$.